# "Not declared in this scope exception" while calling class function

Tags: c++, function

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

struct Employee{
int eno;
string ename;
string job;
float salary;
float bonus;
};

float emp_salary (string emp_job);
float emp_bouns (string emp_job, float emp_salary);

int main(){
Employee emp[5];

cout << "Please enter the employees' details: " << endl;
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cout << "Employee no." << (i+1) << " : " << endl
    << "Employee number : ";
    cin >> emp[i].eno;

    cout << "Name : ";
    cin >> emp[i].ename;

    cout << "Job : ";
    cin >> emp[i].job;
}

for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    emp[i].salary = emp_salary(emp[i].job);
    emp[i].bonus = emp_bonus(emp[i].job, emp[i].salary);
    }

cout << endl << "------------------------------------" << endl;
cout << "Employee's information:";
for(int i = 0; i < 5; i++){
    cout << "Employee no." << (i+1) << " : "
    << "Employee number : " << emp[i].eno << endl
    << "Name : " << emp[i].ename << endl
    << "Job : " << emp[i].job << endl
    << "Salary : " << emp[i].salary << endl
    << "Bonus : " << emp[i].bonus << endl;
}
}
float emp_salary (string job){
float salary;
if(job == "Manager"){
    salary = 5000;
}
else if(job == "Engineer"){
    salary = 3000;
}
else if(job == "Clerk"){
    salary = 2000;
}
else{
    salary = 1000;
}
return salary;
}

float emp_bouns (string emp_job, float emp_salary){
float bonus;
if(emp_job == "Manager"){
    bonus = emp_salary * 1.00;
}
else if(emp_job == "Engineer"){
    bonus = emp_salary * 0.80;
}
else if(emp_job == "Clerk"){
    bonus = emp_salary * 0.60;
}
else{
    bonus = emp_salary * 0.40;
}
return bonus;
}
```

This program is written to get input from user about the employee's details, the function emp_bonus here is used to calculate the bonus they received based on their salary multiply with a percentage based on the employee's job.

It shows error when I call the function emp_bonus(), saying that emp_bonus was not declared in this scope, what does it mean? I should've used the correct parameters in declaration, definition or calling

Comment: There is a typo in function declaration `float emp_bouns`

Comment: Don't you mean `emp_bouns()` ?

Comment: It means that you have called an undeclared function. You may want to correct the typo in the declaration of the function `emp_bouns()`.

Comment: Simple text search for "emp_bonus" should give a big clue what's wrong.

Comment: Oh a silly mistake there, thanks everyone :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You declare emp_b**oun**s and call for emp_b**onu**s

Answer (score 1):

In your code, you have named your function `emp_boUns` but when you are call that method you aren't making that typo. That would be why you are getting the error saying that the `emp_bonus` method is not declared.

**Edit:** Might I recommend looking up [Rubbber ducky debugging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging) . It's an effective countermeasure against this (and many other) kinds of problems.